# How to find matching elements in a single vector

Tags: c++, for-loop, vector

I would like to produce the number of times an element is NOT seen again in the vector. The elements in the vector must be randomized by a seed, in this case, 3.

For example, if numbers 2, 6, and 4 are shown again in the vector with the size of 30, the totalComplete should be 27 since 3 numbers repeat themselves.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    vector<int> seats;
    int totalComplete = 0;
    srand(3);
    seats.resize(30);
    for(int k = 0; k < 20; k++){
        seats.at(k)=(rand()%30);
        cout << seats.at(k);
        cout <<" ";
        totalComplete++;
        for(int j = 0; j < 20; j++){
            if(j != k)
                if(seats.at(k) == seats.at(j))
                    totalComplete--;
        }
        cout<<endl;
    } 
    cout << totalComplete;
    return 0;
}
```

So in my code, the numbers randomly placed in the vector is 6 25 18 0 15 10 12 16 1 4 28 4 3 19 22 21 24 25 1 15. The numbers 25, 15, 1, and 4 repeat themsevles so the totalComplete should be 16. However, my code produces 0. I believe the region where I check if number is repeated is wrong.

Comment: Do you really need that first for loop? Consider breaking your problem into parts. Fill the vector with the data you want to use, then work on finding the duplicates. If you don't need to know which numbers are duplicates you can just `std::sort` and `std::unique`. If you have external restrictions, like if this is a homework assignment, you should spell them out in your question now rather than parcel them out piece by piece as people try to help with things that violate those restrictions.

Comment: The first for loop is for something else, it has nothing to do with finding the amount of elements or inputting the values of the vector. Its supposed to show the number iterations in each vector, but yeah ignore the first for loop.

Comment: Offtopic: You get much better random numbers if you use the new C++ [random number facilities](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random). If you insist on `rand`: Modulo calculation gives rather bad distrubution, better is `rand()*max/(RAND_MAX+1)` (provided the first product does not overflow).

Comment: Offtopic 2: `at` function does range checking, `operator[]` does not. If you are sure that indices *are* in range (`....resize(30); for(...; k < 20;...)`, then you should prefer the latter for efficiency.

Comment: The inner loop iterates up to 20 all the time - fatal, if you insert 0 for one k, as then all the 0 already in the vector will be counted. Additionally, if you insert a value more than twice, then third value will match both values inserted before and subtract one too much (4th two too much, ...). You might change to `for(...; j < k; ...)` (don't need `if(j != k)` inside any more either) and `break` the loop on first match. Of course, this is an `O(n²)` algorithm, there are better ones...

Answer (score 0):

My immediate advice would be to separate the code into small pieces, and test each one separately. I'd start with a function to just fill the array with random numbers. Then I'd write a function to just count unique entries. Test each one in isolation, and check that you're getting what you expect. Then when each one works by itself, put them together to get a complete program that does what you really want.